# Why can't I cd into this Windows mapped drive?

Tags: windows-10, mapped-drive

The drive is like this:

```
\\bigdrive\folder
```

and I mapped it to H: and it works.

But when I try:

```
H:
```

or

```
cd H:\something
```

it complains:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> H:
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'H' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Location $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (V:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command prompt says that you are currently working in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`, which suggests that PowerShell is running as an Administrator. Drive mappings are created per-user, rather than system-wide, so it's likely that the user context in which PowerShell is running does not have drive H: mapped.

Try running PowerShell as a standard user. Or, map the drive within PowerShell:

```
net use H: \\bigdrive\folder
```

Comment: Great that exactly it. Do you know if Windows has a system-wide way to map a drive?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/841949/how-do-i-map-a-network-drive-so-that-any-user-that-logs-in-the-pc-could-see-it-i